# I can't Debug Xamarin.Iso on Iphone 6 in windows 10 (VS 2019 ). What i do wrong?

Tags: iphone, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

my configuration:

- Windows 10 x64
- Visual Studio Community Edition 2019
- Iphone **6** , With IOS 12.5.4

I can run/deploy Xamarin.IOS application on my Iphone **6**, but when i trying to debug - problems arise ((

Xamarin Logo suspends, Sometimes app run without stopping on breakpoints. Maybe Iphone too old?
Please Help!

Comment: Any exceptions or odd logs in "output"? Check if your xcode version matches your VS on windows, check your ios project properties.

Comment: Try to debug on a newer phone to see if problem persists.

Comment: I debug on Iphone 12 and result is perfect! Very fast and debugger stops on break points!! I think this is it - my Iphone 6 too old